Erroneous \underbrace output with libertinus and mathtools (only lualatex and xelatex)
I'm using \underbrace and when I add mathtools to the package list, I get an erroneous output:

An MWE to reproduce this is:
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{libertinus}    
\usepackage{mathtools}    
    
\begin{document}    
    \[    
        \underbrace{\int \dotsi \int}_{N}    
    \]    
\end{document}

Removing mathtools from the preable produces the correct output.
This only happens with lualatex and xelatex, although I just noticed that the math font is not libertinus with pdflatex, so this error does not occur.
I'm on an up-to-date archlinux with texlive 2024.

Ah, of course one notices these things after posting the question. The log file suggest per mathtools warning to load mathtools before unicode-math. Reversing the package order actually solves my problem.
